# When Is A Good Time To Use React Router Replace(componentDidMount?)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that if someone would copy the url and page it in a new tab would crash as it is missing data required from a pervious step.

I want to redirect them to some other page and remove it from their "back" history. So I was thinking of using "replace"

I been doing it on **componentDidMount** but noticed everything just seems to run twice.

```
// Page1Component
    componentDidMount(){


        if(true){
          const { replace } = props.routingStore;
          const params = props.match.params;

          replace('/members/home')
        }
      }
```

So when the above code gets hit, this is what happens

1. Page1Component componentDidMount loads
2. HomeComponent componentDidMount loads
3. Page1Component componentDidMount loads again
4. HomeComponent componentDidMount loads

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) component directly in the `render` method :

```
if(...) {
  return <Redirect to="/members/home" push={false}/>;
}
```

Note that using `push={false}` will replace the current entry into the history

Comment: Intresting, did not know that but still getting the same problem of everything running twice, so maybe I got some other issue.

Comment: Do you declare only once `Page1Component` element ? Maybe the component linked to `/members/home` also render `Page1Component` ?

Comment: Yeah, I checked that out I don't see any evidence of that. In fact if I am on the "homeComponent" and refresh the page only 1 mount happens, it is just when I refresh the page on Page1Component